# asp droplist invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a droplist data bound to a field in a database. I have a defined list of values that I want users to select from going forward, but if a user were to open up an old record, I still want the user to see the current selection.

For my droplist I have added the DataBinding event and added the following code:

```
protected void dbLeadConsultant_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DropDownList dbLeadConsultant = (DropDownList)fvProjectMain.FindControl("dbLeadConsultant");

        try
        {
            dbLeadConsultant.DataBind();
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            var dv = new DataView();
            var dt = new DataTable();

            dv = DSProjects.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
            dt = dv.ToTable();
            string strValue = dt.Rows[0]["LeadConsultant"].ToString();

            ListItem liValue = new ListItem(strValue, strValue);

            dbLeadConsultant.Items.Add(liValue);
            dbLeadConsultant.SelectedValue = "0";
        }
    }
```

This stops the "'dbLeadConsultant' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items" error, but I suspect the issue now is that the dbLeadConsultant_DataBinding now keeps firing ever time the DataBind is called.

How can I stop this looping?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you even have all that code in the `catch`? And it looks like you are creating a loop by binding in the `DataBinding` method. If it weren't for that error the site would crash.

Comment: Yes I understand, If I tried to bind at another time, I would get item not in selection. I have all that code in catch as it only needs to be run if the value cannot be set. Otherwise I don't need to call the data source. Any thoughts? The catch method is mentioned several places online to handle nulls, but I can't find examples to replace with the data it has trouble binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following replaces the event handler:

```
theDropDownList.DataBinding -= new EventHandler(PreventErrorOnbinding);
```

The final code I used to make it dynamic is:

```
protected void PreventErrorOnbinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList theDropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
    theDropDownList.DataBinding -= new EventHandler(PreventErrorOnbinding);

    //Allow a combination of databind and appended data.
    theDropDownList.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

    //Tries to bind the data, if it doesn't exist, it will add it in the selection list.
    try
    {
        theDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        var dv = new DataView();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var ds = new SqlDataSource();

        //Uses the source data to add the missing value
        dv = DSProjects.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
        dt = dv.ToTable();

        string strField = theDropDownList.ID.Substring(theDropDownList.ID.IndexOf("db")+2, theDropDownList.ID.Length - (theDropDownList.ID.IndexOf("db") + 2)); //Couldn't find a way to dynamically reference the DataBind fieldname.
        string strValue = dt.Rows[0][strField].ToString();  

        //Add the value pair.
        ListItem liValue = new ListItem(strValue, strValue);

        theDropDownList.Items.Add(liValue);
        theDropDownList.SelectedValue = strValue;
    }
}
```

I then add PreventErrorOnbinding to the "OnDataBind" event.